# Ex contradictione quodlibet and Contradiction elimination

Tags: logic

Are "Ex contradictione quodlibet" and "Contradiction elimination" two different names for the same rule in classical logic? Or are there differences between them?

E.g.:

1. P (Assumption)
2. ¬P (Assumption)
3. ⊥ (Contradiction introduction: 1, 2)
4. Q (Contradiction elimination: 3 or Ex contradictione quodlibet: 3 ?)

Comment: Yes, Fitch system call Contra elim the Ex falso rule